# Java Programming Language Event Mouseclicked

Tags: java

When I double clicked the table of the specific person details, the dialog frame pop out, but its details could not be included.
What shall I do? I need the details inside the table to also display in the new dialog frame that pops out.

Comment: What framework? Swing/AWT/JavaFX/SWT/GWT/HTML ... ?

Comment: you also need to post some code here so that we may see what you are up to.

Comment: You didn't mention the framework, but if you had searched for just 5 minutes on Google, you would have found 1000x articles and tutorials about your issue. Do your research before posting here. We're not here to make your homework or for trivial stuff which Google can answer instantly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't any code its hard to tell. But you can use MouseClick event to your table modal and get all the data into public arrays,struct or some variables. Then you can set them into the text fields of your new pop up window by setText method.Thats the simple and the easiest way possible. Or if you don't want new pop up window you can simply set the details in table into text fields or whatever you want by inserting MouseClick event.